# Replace affects all strings in an array

Tags: javascript

I am having some issues about replacing. I am fetching some integers from DB. And if the number fetched is **just** **1** then I replace it with "empty", but when I do that, it affects all numbers that have 1 in them.

Here is what I am doing, first calling `toString` and then `replace`

```html
<tr v-if="moreIndex < one.length"　 v-for="moreIndex in morePro">
  <td>{{one[moreIndex].products}}</td>
  <td>{{priceSep(one[moreIndex].price).toString().replace("1", "empty")}}</td>
</tr>
```

So I am changing "1" to empty but if any other data has includes 1 then output look like this...

```
5empty98
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: If you get the input "1" you want to change it to "empty", but if you get "something1", you do not want to touch it all? Could you provide inputs and expected values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the *length* with [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
.:

```
<td>{{priceSep(one[moreIndex].price).toString().length == 1 ? priceSep(one[moreIndex].price).toString().replace("1", "empty") : priceSep(one[moreIndex].price).toString()}}</td>
```

May be, you can try directly set the value if the value is 1:

```
<td>{{priceSep(one[moreIndex].price).toString() == "1" ? "empty" : priceSep(one[moreIndex].price).toString()}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of the string before replacing it

```
{{priceSep(one[moreIndex].price).toString().length > ? 
  priceSep(one[moreIndex].price).toString() :
  priceSep(one[moreIndex].price).toString().replace("1", "empty")
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegExp:

```
{{priceSep(one[moreIndex].price).toString().replace(/^1$/, "empty")}}
```